# android drawing bitmap above another

Tags: android, bitmap

In certain case I have to add a Bitmap on top of another. But my code doesn't work. Of course I really think, I am not doing the right thing but I don't know how to do this works.

After that I have to convert my Bitmap to a Picture object and then add my Picture object to my MarkerOption object.

Here my code :

```
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lifr);
                Bitmap bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.manche_a_air);
                Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight() / 2, null);
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmOverlay));

                return markerOptions;
```

If anyone has an idea ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: why dont you use BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmOverlay) ?

Answer (score 0):

I would make a FrameLayout (*Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top*) with the 2nd layout having a transparent background. Note that the 2nd bitmap also may be partially transparent. If I needed to move the 2nd image at run-time, I would change the layout parameters programmatically.

Sort of:

```
<FrameLayout ...>
  <LinearLayout  ...>
     <!-- the 1st bitmap goes here -->
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:background="#80000000" ...> <!-- semi-transparent -->
     <View android:layout_width="80px" .../> <!-- just padding -->
     <!-- the 2nd bitmap goes here -->
     ...
  </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Note that for precise positioning, you may use a horizontal LinearLayout inside a vertical LinearLayout.

Changing the position programmatically is a bit tricky, you may have to intercept  onGlobalLayout().

This, of course, is ok for UI but probably too slow for gaming.